# nuxt router-module render function or template not defined in component: anonymous

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router, server-side-rendering

when i remove '@nuxtjs/router' from build modules in nuxt.config.js file, the error will solve.

Reproduction link
https://github.com/mahdikmg/nuxt-router-module-bug

just install dependencies, run the project and open it in your browser.

[image: bug]

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't checked it but my guess is that your custom route you're pointing to is in the `/pages` folder.
As mentioned in the documentation, the module entirely disables the folder for automatic routes. Did you try to move your pages to another folder? (let's say `/routes`)

Comment: yes im aware of that. i didnt use pages folder at all. but changed my plan. im using nuxt router now. thank you for your comment